# Created SSH user on apache for specific directory, getting packet_write_wait: Connection to <my IP> port 22: Broken pipe error

Tags: apache, ssh

My directory path is `/var/www/my virtual host/public_html`
I want to create a new ssh user which will have permission to my virtual host directory.

I have taken below steps.

```
groupadd sftpusers
useradd -g sftpusers -d /var/www/my virtual host -s /bin/bash  username
```

Then i edit my sshd file

```
vi /etc/ssh/sshd_config
Subsystem sftp internal-sftp
Match group sftpusers
ChrootDirectory %h
ForceCommand internal-sftp

sudo service ssh restart
```

Then i changed user for directory like

```
chown -R username:sftpusers /var/www/my virtual host
```

Then i set the password for the user
But when i try to SSH to the server with this user. I get error as 'packet_write_wait: Connection to  port 22: Broken pipe
'
Does anyone have any idea about what am I missing here?

Comment: What access mode is your home directory ; /var/www/my virtual host? I think that it must be 750 if you assumed allowing group access.

Comment: @Deain. No. It is 755

Answer (score 0):

It turned out i had wrong permissions to `/my virtual host/` dir. I set to `username:groupname` which should have been `root:root`. Changed it accordingly. And it worked.